# Organization of time insensitive content

Tags: posts, pages, customization

I'm planning to use WordPress to maintain and publish a role-playing system. Is there a best practice for managing content in WordPress that isn't time sensitive?

Should I use pages and make short notification posts when those are updated? I know posts and pages are stored the same, it's handling the creation and presentation that's giving me trouble. I want updates to be obvious, but without republishing entire sections of content.

Comment: I'm having a really difficult time understanding what you want to do, can you broaden the scope of the question and explain what it is that you're trying to do with the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) (and, likely, [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)).

Some intrepid developers did just that, for a proof-of-concept game built on WordPress, and [presented it at WordCamp Toronto 2011](http://wordpress.tv/2012/01/26/mark-reale-khori-armstrong-using-wordpress-to-build-interactive-games/).

Comment: kool video. +1 for wasting my time ;)